# How to fill an array through this cycle in a telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I am writing a bot for the telegram "Matrix Calculator". For the code to work correctly, I need to fill in the matrix array, but when the code starts, the loop simply does not work and the code immediately proceeds to perform another function ()

```
n1=0
m1=0
n2=0
m2=0
matrixchlen=0
matrix = []

@bot.message_handler(commands=['5'])

def UmnMatNaChislo1(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Введите значение количества строк матрицы А:\n')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message,nn1)

def nn1(message):
    global n1
    ni1 = message.text.strip()
    n1=int(ni1)
    UmnMatNaChislo2(message)

def UmnMatNaChislo2(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Введите значение количества столбцов матрицы А:\n')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, mm1)

def mm1(message):
    global m1
    mi1 = message.text.strip()
    m1=int(mi1)
    UmnMatNaChislo3(message)

def UmnMatNaChislo3Range(message):
    global matrix
    global matrixchlen
    global n1
    global m1
    for i in range(n1):
        matrixchleninput = message.text.strip()
        matrixchlen=int(matrixchleninput)
        matrix += [[matrixchlen for k in range(m1)]]
    UmnMatNaChislo5(message)

def UmnMatNaChislo5(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Введите число, на которое требуется умножить матрицу А\n")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, lint)
```

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something but is n1 equal to zero?

Comment: No, n1 is not equal to 0. I edited the code in the question, you can see

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.